# Nginx returns bad gateway when forwarding even when service is up and running and port is correct

Tags: nginx, port-forwarding, gitea

I set up Nginx 1.23.2 on Debian 10 to forward specific requests to port 3999 on which gitea is running at.

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen                  443 ssl;
        server_name             www.subdomain.domain.com subdomain.domain.com;
        access_log              logs/subdomain.domain.com.access.log main;
        
        ssl_certificate         /home/gitea/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/gitea/ssl/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        location / {
                proxy_pass                              https://127.0.0.1:3999/;
                proxy_set_header                        Host    $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        &proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Part of output from nginx -T command proving that configuration is picked up:

```
...
# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/gitea.ispf.sk.conf:
server {
        listen                  443 ssl;
        server_name             www.subdomain.domain.com subdomain.domain.com;
        access_log              logs/subdomain.domain.com.access.log main;

        ssl_certificate         /home/gitea/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/gitea/ssl/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        location / {
                proxy_pass                              https://127.0.0.1:3999/;
                proxy_set_header                        Host    $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        &proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
...
```

(Obviously domain name is changed)

However when I enter [www.subdomain.domain.com](http://www.subdomain.domain.com) i get 502 bad gateway error.

Output from **ss -tulpn** command proving that nginx is listening at 443 and gitea is running at 3999 port:

```
Netid            State             Recv-Q            Send-Q                       Local Address:Port                        Peer Address:Port            Process                                                                                                                                                      
tcp              LISTEN            0                 511                                0.0.0.0:443                              0.0.0.0:*                users:(("nginx",pid=306831,fd=8),("nginx",pid=306830,fd=8),("nginx",pid=306829,fd=8))                                                                      
tcp              LISTEN            0                 4096                                     *:3999                                   *:*                users:(("gitea",pid=305999,fd=14))
```

Server part of gitea configuration:

```
[server]
SSH_DOMAIN       = subdomain.domain.com
DOMAIN           = subdomain.domain.com
HTTP_ADDR        = 0.0.0.0
HTTP_PORT        = 3999
DISABLE_SSH      = true
OFFLINE_MODE     = false
```

Gitea version is 1.17.3. I can access gitea when I enter *SERVER IP ADDRESS*:3999 into the address bar in browsers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try "proxy_pass http" instead of "proxy_pass https".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app.ini` does not contain

```
[server]
PROTOCOL = https
```

The protocol [defaults](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/config-cheat-sheet/#server-server) to plain `http`, and the purpose of the reverse proxy is to add the TLS encryption, as described in [HTTPS setup to encrypt connections to Gitea](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/https-setup/#using-a-reverse-proxy).

Therefore, you need

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3999/;
```

with `http://` instead of `https://`.

Additionally, you might want to prevent direct non-TLS connections with

```
[server]
HTTP_ADDR = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I am not listening on port 80 by nginx, so i kept proxy_pass with https. Additionally i had to define CERT_FILE and KEY_FILE in gitea app.ini. Thanks for help.

Comment: The `proxy_pass http://` has nothing to do with port 80, though. The additional TLS between Nginx and Gitea on the same host does not add much.

Comment: What is really happening when nginx server listen is using ssl and i forward request to http only as in your answer? Is the request still encrypted between nginx and gitea? Is response from gitea unencrypted when it goes back to nginx and nginx encrypts it? I did it as in your answer, its working, and i am interested. Could you/someone give some material on this topic?

Comment: It's unencrypted but as it's on the local loopback interface, there's not much room form MitM.